# Get list of friend who installed particular facebook application

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I can get list of my friends who installed skype application using below URL.

> ```
> https://www.facebook.com/browse/friends_using_app/?app_id=260273468396
> ```

I want to fetch this list in fql or graph api but unable to find any query or anything related to this. Anyone know how to achieve this.

Thanks For reading my Question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to find what apps friends are using?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/13253993/is-it-possible-to-find-what-apps-friends-are-using)

Comment: i want to find list of friends who uses other app not my own app.

Comment: And that’s what the other question is about, basically. Answer stays the same: Not possible.